# Spring Boot Bitbucket Pilpline to ECR

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

I try to build a CI/CD Pipeline with Bitbucket-Pipelines.
My dockerized Spring Boot Application should be pushed to my AWS ECR. But when the pipeline executes the docker commands it throws an error:

> COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat target/app.jar: file does not exist

Does anyone set up a similar pipeline and can help me out?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/app.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Here is my pipeline yaml config:

```
image: maven:3.6.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Clean install
        script:
          - cd path.to.file
          - mvn clean install -DskipTests
    - step:
        name: Push to ECR
        services:
          - docker # Enable Docker for your repository
        script:
          # build the image
          - cd path.to.dockerfile
          - docker build -t app-devtest .

          # use the pipe to push the image to AWS ECR
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:1.4.2
            variables:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              IMAGE_NAME: app-devtest
              TAGS: 'latest'
```

Comment: Can you try to use WORKDIR to clarify your working directory in Dockerfile?

Comment: probably the problem .... mvn clean install + push to ecr in one step does the trick

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your dockerfile. This `COPY target/app.jar app.jar` will work in your local workspace, because you already have the jar locally (it is created when you run your app). In the VM where the pipeline is running, there is no provision to build the jar file over there, so the `app.jar` is missing.

To fix the issue, first you will need to tell maven to name your jar file using the name you give it; in this case "app". In the pom file of your project, add the following.

```
<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
</build>
```

Then you will need to build the project in the docker build process and then copy your jar file. So the docker file should look something like below.

```
# first stage: use a maven project to clean package the application
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-11-slim AS MAVEN_BUILD

COPY / /home/myapp/

# Building the jar file using maven
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

# second stage: use open jdk 11.0.11 image to build the project docker image
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine

# copy jar needed from the first stage and discard the rest
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /home/myapp/app.jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar

EXPOSE 80

# set the startup command to execute the jar
CMD java -jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar
```

The above uses a 2 stage docker build process which creates a lightweight docker image.

This should be enough to solve the issue.

> COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by
> .dockerignore: stat target/app.jar: file does not exist